# ASP.NET: How can I log User's View and Update Gridview in WebPage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview, logging

I have a `LOG` table like this.

`Process_Type` (Could be *Update*, *View*), 
`Username`, `Date`

In my page I have only one `Gridview`.

I want to log user's information (username, date, process_type) in `LOG` table.

1.**View**

Should I use `Page_Load()` function? (Because `Gridview` binding on the load of page) I think I should update my table like this;

```
UPDATE LOG
SET PROCESS_TYPE = 'VIEW', USERNAME =  Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"],
DATE = DateTime.Now
```

2.**UPDATE**

Should I use `Gridview1_OnRowUpdating()` function ? I think I should update my table like this;

```
UPDATE LOG
SET PROCESS_TYPE = 'UPDATE', USERNAME =  Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"],
DATE = DateTime.Now
```

Is this a good plan for logging my simple page?

Or, How can I do that more easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log the View, you should use `DataBound` and for update use `RowUpdated`

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // is Called when data is binded to gridview
}
protected void GridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    // is called when Row is Updated
}
```

Comment: @Muhammed My Gridview bound at the load of page. Should I Updating process in `GridView1_DataBound` is better than `Page_Load` ? I don't understand why? Secondly, I aggree with you I should use `GridView1_RowUpdated`..

Comment: DataBound event is called once the gridview successfully binded the data. This will make sure Data is binded for view and your log are accurate. On the other hand, if there was problem in databinding to gridview, you are still updating the log, it will inaccurate your log results.